# Should I still create an EJB JAR in Java EE6+ for web apps?

Tags: ejb, java-ee-6, java-ee-7

Since Java EE6, it is possible to put in EJBs in WAR files.  Is there still any good technical reason to separate them?  I am looking specifically for something I can only do with EJB JARs that I really cannot do with EJBs embedded in a WAR.

One may say for modularity, but honestly I find modularity using separate JAR files is a waste of time and extra plumbing and classpath headaches for something that would only be used together (if we do need to separate it later, it is just a matter of refactoring into a separate JAR if needed).  Extra dependencies such as guava are different as they are not EJBs.

Another advantage to keeping everything in the WAR is you don't even need an EAR file if you don't want to (aside from setting up the context-root in a standard fashion).  The WAR file can contain all the support dependencies such as guava and the ilk.

Another one may be for apps that are not "web apps" which would make sense, but the majority of things I work with are web apps anyway which is why I qualified the question "for web apps".

I am not listing EJB client apps and their interfaces.  In reality I would use Web Services rather than something language specific to handle this form of connectivity.

In theory I can do webservices in EJB, but that does not work on all containers specifically websphere which requires you to build a Web Router project which is basically another WAR file.

So is there still any good *technical reason* to separate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No technical reason, no.  We did a pretty good job at the specification level in EJB 3.1 where this was introduced to make the transition as smooth as possible.

The one place we fell short is around the topic of the `ejb-jar.xml` file.  A webapp can only have a single `WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml` file.  This is true even if you have ejbs in jar files under `WEB-INF/lib/`.  If those jars happen to contain `META-INF/ejb-jar.xml` files, they are ignored.

This was on purpose as the `ejb-jar.xml` contains the ability to define things in a sort of "global" fashion, such as default transaction attribute, security constraints, default interceptors.  It was ultimately decided merging this all in some way was awkward.

I personally expected to hear more complaining than we have -- so far I've heard no one mention that they find only being allowed one ejb-jar.xml for the entire webapp as limiting.  However, should people suddenly start complaining, we could introduce a `ejb-fragement.xml` concept in the same vein as the Servlet `web-fragment.xml` so configuration could be packaged with the jars in the `WEB-INF/lib/` directory.

Certainly, if you're reading this and you have a preference upvote the comment below.

Comment: Please add the ability to put an `META-INF/ejb-jar.xml` inside the `WEB-INF/lib/` jars webapps.

Comment: To be honest I haven't found single EJB-JAR to be limiting since it is usually a global thing as you said.  What I did find annoying was trying to figure out whether it should be in WEB-INF or META-INF.  To date I have to always look at my reference app that worked to know where the descriptors go.

Comment: Choosing this as the best answer

Answer (score 0):

The one reason that comes to my mind is using EJB module as business logic which is shared by many web modules that can be combined in one Enterprise application.

Suppose you would like to offer same functionality via plain web application, rest, Web Service. Each of these interfaces could be provided by separate web module (for example if one customer would like to have WS api in addition to web app but not Rest, etc).
Then you could combine your application with these web modules, but share business logic via one EJB module. Copying EJB to each module would be troublesome and you might have to play with bindings as each web module would need to register its beans.

I know, its a bit invented, improbable example, but...

Second example would be - whenever you consider using remote interfaces. This means that you intend to use it for many different clients/web apps and EJB module should be more independent in that case and not embedded in web module.

These are both kind of modularity examples. Maybe others will have different ones.

Comment: ya those are modularity examples which I sort of dismissed in my question text.  I am able to put in all the REST, WebService and actual web app on the WAR.  I still have a separate (non-EJB module) for my integration tests that work with Cargo, but that does not apply as it isn't an EJB.

Comment: Unrelated note -- check out Arquillian for Java EE testing as an alternative to Cargo.

Comment: Unrelated note -- I have tried Arqualian before.  I liked it for certain things, but I preferred Cargo in the end as it is an *actual container*

Answer (score 0):

> Since Java EE6, it is possible to put in EJBs in WAR files. Is there still any good technical reason to separate them?

In order to be compliant with some specific *security requirements*, your database and business logic must be isolated from the outside. E.g.: They must run in a different machine located in a more protected LAN. The application layer exposed directly to the Internet is just the one that executes on the Web server and contains only your presentation logic.

Another advantage of having your application composed with more than one deployable, it's that you can isolate each other. E.g.; in some enterprise applications it could be a problem  if some minor change in the presentation logic, forces you to update/redeploy a very stable business component.

Comment: Actually I thought of that and when I look at most (not all) enterprise web apps you deploy the whole thing anyway rather than separate the web portion from the database portion.  You're right in that you need it for separate machines though.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a technical reason for this.  Though I am not sure if it is a technical reason because of the specification or if it is a bug in the reference implementation.

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class ...
```

Does not function correctly on Glassfish 4.1 at the moment when deploying in a WAR file.  It does not expose the end point as expected, but works flawlessly in an EJB.